# Eigenvalues from Symmetric Matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, real-numbers, diagonalization

I found a past final exam from [here](https://www.math.ubc.ca/Ugrad/pastExams/Files/307_2006WT1_sec101.pdf)

> Consider the real matrix
>
> $
>    A =
>   \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
>    1 & 0 & 1   \\
>    0 & 1 & 0  \\
>    1 & 0 & 1   \\
>   \end{array} } \right]
> $
>
> (a) Explain what property the matrix A has, which assures that you can diagonalize it without the help of complex matrix.
>
> (b) find a real matrix S and a diagonal matrix D, such that
>
> $A=SDS^T$

For part (a), I thought the matrix is symmetric, but I am not sure how to find the eigenvalue for that..

For part (b), how do I get the eigenvalue from A?

Comment: Hint: zero is an eigenvalue - but how?

Comment: @SeanRoberson how do you know?

Comment: Columns one and three are identical, hence the columns of $A$ do not span $\mathbb{R}^3$, and so $A$ is not invertible, meaning... (finish this).

Comment: You can find all three eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors by looking at the columns of the matrix and at simple linear combinations of them.

Comment: @amd could you pls tell me the thought process? I only know how to get eigenvalue and eigenvectors by diagonalizing the matrix :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out and here's the thought process:

(1) If you notice the matrix is symmetrical, we can try to come up with an eigenvalue that can make the diagonal to all 0s. So we can try eigenvalue = 1, which makes the new matrix into :
$ \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   0 & 0 & 1   \\
   0 & 0 & 0  \\
   1 & 0 & 0   \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

Therefore we are able to construct the corresponding eigenvector into 
$\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   0    \\
   1  \\
   0  \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

(2) You could also make eigenvalue equals to 0, so we can have a new matrix of
$ \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 0 & 1   \\
   0 & 1 & 0  \\
   1 & 0 & 1   \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$
So we can have a new eigenvector of 
$\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   -1    \\
   0  \\
   1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

(3) Since we got eigenvalues of 0 and 1, according to the trace of the matrix, it is 1 + 1 + 1 = 3, so we can find the other eigenvalue of 3 - 1 - 0 = 2.

In conclusion: the 3 eigenvalues are: 1, 0 and 2

Answer (score 3):

Recall that the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis and that when you right-multiply a matrix by a vector, the result is a linear combination of the columns of the matrix with coefficients given by the components of the vector.

The second column of $A$ is $(0,1,0)^T$, so that standard basis vector gets mapped to itself: it is an eigenvector of $1$. The sum of the first and third columns is $(2,0,2)^T=2(1,0,1)^T$, so $(1,0,1)$ is an eigenvector of $2$. Since the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace, you get the third eigenvalue for free: it’s $1+1+1-1-2=0$, but then, we already knew that $0$ is an eigenvalue because the matrix has two identical columns, therefore has a nontrivial null space. You can either compute a basis for this null space to find an eigenvector of $0$ or notice that because the first and third columns are identical, their *difference*, i.e., the product of the matrix with $(1,0,-1)^T$, is $0$.

Since the problem wants an *orthogonal* diagonalization—$SDS^T$ instead of $SDS^{-1}$—you’ll need to orthonormalize the above eigenvectors. They’re already mutually orthogonal (as eigenvectors of a symmetric real matrix of different eigenvalues are), so all you need to do is normalize them.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Observe the matrix, and find a nice permutation matrix (P = P^T = P^-1)
\begin{equation}
P = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
so we can make
\begin{equation}
A = P\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}P^T
\end{equation}
(2) Now we only need to focus on that similar matrix B we made.It's easy to see that B has eigenvalue 1. And because dim(null(B)) = 1 ,we know that B must have a eigenvalue 0.Next, using trace to know the third eigenvalue is 2.
(3)Notice the fact that first two row sum are equal, so we can come up with one eigenvector 
\begin{equation}
v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
corresponding to eigenvalue 2
Second, find the null vector of  B. 
\begin{equation}
v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
corresponding to eigenvalue 0
(4)Normalize and combine each vector, and then we can get
\begin{equation}
U = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt2} & 0\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt2} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
is an unitary matrix, so U^T = U^-1 (also U^T = U)
(5)Finally, we have
\begin{equation}
A = PU\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}U^TP^T
\end{equation}
how nice!
(note: U^T*P^T = (PU)^T)